# Huge Pages on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, kernel

Recently I installed CentOS 6.6, but when I tried to configure Huge Pages, I cannot see the common paths that I am already using to configure hugepages in other CentOS 6 machines, but with the 2.6 kernel series.

I am guessing that is something related with some change in the kernel, but I didn't find a solution...

```
[root@host01 mm]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

[root@host01 mm]# uname -a
Linux oradb03.linea9.int 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 7 11:35:27 CET 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@host01 mm]# grep Huge /proc/meminfo
[root@host01 mm]#

[root@host01 mm]# sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=400
error: "vm.nr_hugepages" is an unknown key
```

Answer (score 0):

CentOS and RedHat 6 are best run on a 2.6 series kernel due to how the distro favors stability versus the newer features. It is likely that your 3.14 kernel doesn't have hugepages configured. What does your /boot/config file say?

E.g. from my CentOS 6.6 server

```
[root@workstation ~]# grep -i huge /boot/config-2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 
CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE=y
CONFIG_HUGETLBFS=y
CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE=y
```